# Trouble implementing a queue in C

Tags: c, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue in c.  I have gotten as far as implementing an enqueue function in my code. However, when I am testing it I don't get the desired output. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
struct queue{

     int array[30];
     int *front; //pointer to front of queue
     int *rear;  //pointer to rear of queue

     int count; //counts number of elements in queue
 };
```

//initialising a queue

```
struct queue * new_Queue()
{

     struct queue *q;
     q->count=0;
     q->front=&q->array[-1];
     q->rear=&q->array[-1];

     return q;
};

int queueCount(struct queue *q)
{
     return q->count;
}

int isFull(struct queue *q)
{
     if(q->count==30){
         printf("%s","Buffer is full!");
         return 1;
     }

return 0;
}

int isEmpty(struct queue *q)
{

     if(q->count==0){
         printf("%s","Queue is empty!");
         return 1;
     }
return 0;
}



int enqueue(struct queue * q,int i)
{

     if(isFull(q)){
         return 0;
     }

     if(isEmpty(q)){
         q->front+1;

     }

     int k=*(q->rear+1);

     q->array[k]=i;
     printf("enque success!");


     return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
     int i=10;

     struct queue *newQueue;

     enqueue(newQueue,i);
     int j= queueCount(newQueue);
     printf("%d",j);

}
```

Comment: `struct queue *newQueue = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));` and `int k=*(q->rear)+1;`

Comment: What Milind said, plus you should acutally call `new_Queue`. As is, both `newQueue` pointers (in `main`and `new_Queue`)  point nowhere.

Comment: And `q->front=NULL;     q->rear=NULL;`

Comment: Ok guys thanks a lot for the feedback! Will look into this and let you know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need memory for your queue. At the moment, you have an uninitialised pointer that points to a random location in memory. Dereferencing that pointer is undefined behaviour and will very likely give you a seg fault.

You have to decide how you want to store your queue. You can either allocate it on the heap with `malloc`. This is what your function `new_Queue` should do:

```
struct queue *new_Queue()
{
    struct queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));    // TO DO: Error checking

    q->count = 0;
    q->front = q->array;
    q->rear = q->array;

    return q;
}
```

You client code then looks like this:

```
struct *q = new_Queue();

enqueue(q, x);
// Do more stuff ...

free(q);     // Release resources
```

The queue structure isn't big. You can also allocate it on the stack. In that casen you need an initialisation function :

```
void queue_init(struct queue *q)
{
    q->count = 0;
    q->front = q->array;
    q->rear = q->array;
}
```

and call it like:

```
struct queue *q;

queue_init(&q);
enqueue(&q, 12);
```

Note the addres-of operator `&`. You  don't have to (and cannot) `free` the queue here.

You can't access the array at index `-1`. You could make the front the next element to dequeue and the rear point to the space where the next element is enqueued. In a circular buffer, that will make the cases of empty and full list indistiguishable, but you can use the `count` to distinguish between them.

Comment: Actually I adjusted my queue to a circular buffer cause turns out that's what I need. Anyways, I seem to be getting a Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code 1....)   at the init_Queue function when I'm enqueuing an int... it appears on the line q->count=0; ...anyone know why?

Comment: Let me guess: Because `q` is an uninitialised pointer that points nowhere, so that dereferencing it with `*` or `->` is undefined behaviour. (I thought you already implemented your queue as circular buffer with `front`  and `rear` as markers of where the data starts and ends.)

Comment: I fail to see what I'm doing wrong :/  i entered your code for the init function exactly like above  `void queue_init(struct queue *q)
{
    q->count = 0;
    q->front = q->array;
    q->rear = q->array;
} `

Comment: "Bad access" tells you that you access memory that you can't access. Most likely you are dereferencing uninitialised or `NULL` pointers. You should get acquainted with debugging in oder to resolve such problems.